# py to exe : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert my python file to an exe using the following library :

```
pyinstaller --onfile -w xxx.py
```

I also tried with the flags but I get the following error :

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Could you add the "xxy.py"? WIthout it, it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Run pyinstaller and stop it to generate the spec file :

`pyinstaller filename.py`

A file with .spec extension should be generated

Now add the following lines to the beginning of the spec file :

`import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)`

Now run the spec file using :

`pyinstaller filename.spec`